# CSS :after element only briefly flashes when refresh

Tags: css

Here's the website I'm working on: https://zemmyang.github.io/jaguar-sundae/, the code can be viewed here: https://github.com/zemmyang/jaguar-sundae, and I'm following the tutorial to make arrows from here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/.

If you refresh the website, I see tiny arrows underneath the header text ("Work History," "Location," etc), but then they disappear after the page fully loads. I've tried it with Chrome and Firefox.

This is the code that styles the header text:

```
.title .cat-title {
    margin-right: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background: #249EBD;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    min-width: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -6px;
    min-height: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.title .cat-title:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 100%;
    margin-left: -10px;
    bottom: -10px;
    border-top: 10px solid #249EBD;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

The thing is, it used to work in [the original](https://ddbullfrog.github.io/resumecard/), which used a different font set (Font Awesome 4.something). I needed new icons, so I switched to the latest version of Font Awesome (5.7.2) and now I get this problem. I didn't touch the CSS at all.

Answer (score 0):

remove `:after` of `svg` and add below css in your css file. added your `:after` css of `svg` to `a.hidebtn`. hope this helps. thanks

```
a.hidebtn:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
left: 20px;
top: 34px;
margin-left: -10px;
bottom: -10px;
border-top: 10px solid #249EBD;
border-left: 10px solid transparent;
border-right: 10px solid transparent;
```